# Quoting parameters in R

Tags: r, function, parameters, macros, metaprogramming

For testing purpose, I want to have a new kind of assignment operator, say `%<-%`, that saves the value to a file when performing the assignment. This basically means I can check whether different invocations of a function return the same value.

For example, if I write `answer %<-% 42`, I expect `42` to be assigned to the object `answer`, and at the same time have an `answer.rds` created in my working directory for which `readRDS('answer.rds') == 42`.

I tried using `substitute` and other utilities, but didn't get how to quote the parameters properly.

```
> `%<-%` <- function(name, value) {name <- value; dput(name)}
> answer %<-% 42
42
> `%<-%` <- function(name, value) {name <- value; dput(substitute(name))}
> answer %<-% 42
42
> `%<-%` <- function(name, value) {name <- value; dput(quote(name))}
> answer %<-% 42
name
```

Comment: Why did you use `dput(name)`, instead of something like `saveRDS(value, paste0(name, '.rds'))`?

Comment: @DavidKlotz Sorry for the confusion. I think this is a better way to show you what the problem is, because the error message of `saveRDS(paste0(name, '.rds'))` isn't very helpful: `Error in saveRDS(paste0(name, ".rds")) : 'file' must be non-empty string`

Comment: Sorry, I don't know if you saw my edit.  Should be `saveRDS(value, paste0...))`

Comment: @DavidKlotz In that case, I got a `42.rds`, probably because `name` is evaluated when used in the call to `saveRDS`.

Comment: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To turn the unevaluated expression into a character string you should use `deparse(substitute(x))`

In your example something like this should work:

```r
`%<-%` <- function(name, value) {
  assign(deparse(substitute(name)), value, envir = .GlobalEnv)
  saveRDS(value, paste0(deparse(substitute(name)),'.rds'))
}
```

```r
answer %<-% 1

answer
#[1] 1

readRDS('answer.rds')
#[1] 1
```

**Edit**:

As you point out in your comment, it does make more sense for this function to use `inherits = T` rather than always assign to the global environment, so:

```r
`%<-%` <- function(name, value) {
  assign(deparse(substitute(name)), value, inherits = T)
  saveRDS(value, paste0(deparse(substitute(name)),'.rds'))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! BTW, personally I would prefer `assign(deparse(substitute(name)), value, inherits=TRUE)` in case of variable shadowing.

Comment: Can you be more explicit about what are you going to replace `assign` with?

Comment: @nalzok sorry deleted comment and didn't see you responded. Disregard it anyway, I jumped the gun and my hunch didn't work.